# Have Peter Parker and Peter Quill ever met each other in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In this first look on *Avengers: Infinity War*, we see the actors of Peter Parker/Spider-Man and Peter Quill/Star-Lord standing right next to each other:

Given this, I would like to know: did these two ever meet in the comics?

Comment: They've met in the _Ultimate Spider-Man_ cartoon, at least: https://comicvine.gamespot.com/ultimate-spider-man-217-guardians-of-the-galaxy/4070-3462/

Comment: Although Spider-Man is on the cover of issue #1 of [Guardians Team-Up Vol 1](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_Team-Up_Vol_1), and Quill appears in these issues, the individual issue pages list only Spider-Woman, not Spider-Man. So unless someone owns these issues and can check, this doesn't seem like it fits the bill.

Comment: [Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 4 #14](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_4_14) is more promising – it lists both Star-Lord/Quill and Spider-Man as characters, but they both appear in flashbacks, and I don't know if they appear in the _same_ flashbacks – again, if someone has it, they could check.

Answer (score 5):

In [Guardians Team-Up #9](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Guardians_Team-Up_Vol_1_9) opens with Peter Quill going after Spider-Man to recover his father's gun. It turns out the gun was stolen by another character disguised as Spider-Man and they team up.

Comment: Do they go where the riverboat sails tonight? Is there fighting there? Does the company need men?

Answer (score 2):

@Jack's answer is the most accurate as *Guardians Team-Up* #9 (2015) is the only time Peter Quill and Spider-Man actually *meet* each other, i.e. talk to each other, act together etc.

However, there are two other instances of these two "meeting"... in a way.

- As pointed out by @tobiasvl in [a comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160644/have-peter-parker-and-peter-quill-ever-met-each-other#comment423480_160644)<sup>1</sup>, *Guardians of the Galaxy* #14 (2016) has a long flashback of the Guardians (including Flash Thompson) rescuing Spider-Man from the Skrulls. When Spidey's brought to the Guardians' ship, he's out cold and they drop him back on Earth, so while Peter Quill somehow met Spider-Man, Spidey didn't meet Quill per se (as he has no recollection of what happened).

  [image: The Guardians surround an unconscious Spider-Man]

- "Zodiac", the first arc of the 2012 *Avengers Assemble* run, has the Avengers teaming up with the Guardians of the Galaxy to defeat Thanos. In issue #8, everyone of them joins the fight on Earth for the final fight, including Star-Lord and Spider-Man. While they don't talk to each other, and the Guardians leave shortly after, you know... Beating Thanos' butt builds bonds?

  [image: a lot of heroes surrounding a defeated Thanos, including Star-Lord and Spider-Man]

---

<sup>1</sup> As per [their other comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160644/have-peter-parker-and-peter-quill-ever-met-each-other#comment423479_160644), no, Spider-Man isn't featured in *Guardians Team-Up* #1 (2015), he's only on the cover.